# chocolatey install blocked by antivirus on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, chocolatey

I'm trying to install chocolatey package manager on my local machine as administrator using instructions given on https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#install-with-powershell.exe
I opened powershell as administrator and with ExecutionPolicy set as bypass I pasted the command given on the website.
I get the following error:
At line:1 char:1

```
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.Service ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your antivirus software.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptContainedMaliciousContent
```

I have McAfee installed and turned on. which setting should I turn off in McAfee and windows defender so as to be able to install chocolatey on my system.

Comment: McAfee enterprise? Or a local install? You should be able to disable real-time detection on a local install, but if it's enterprise you might need to get an exception added.

Comment: @spikey_richie thanks I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to update Chocolatey using the Windows PowerShell script by temporarily turning off McAfee Real-Time scanning and then running PowerShell (as an admin) and using the documented script.